# SQL Server 2000 TSQL : Stored proc results into table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I would like to get the out put of a stored proc call and create a permanent table with out specifying columns. Because the stored proc return lots of columns...

So.. how can I do this??

```
SELECT * INTO MYTABLE FROM MYSTOREDPROC @PARAM1 = 1, @PARAM2 = 'HELLO'
```

is it possible??

Example would help me alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't generate the table from calling stored procedure.  However, edit the called stored procedure and alter the select that generates the result set to have an *INTO YourNewTable* clause:

```
SELECT
   columns....
   INTO YourNewTable
   from ...
   where
   order by...
```

Run the procedure 1 time, to generate the table. remove the changes (*INTO YourNewTable* clause) and then call the procedure as:

```
INSERT INTO YourNewTable
    EXEC YourProcedure params...
```